# Read HTML table using R directly from a website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to read covid data directly from government website: https://pikobar.jabarprov.go.id/distribution-case#

I did that using `rvest` library

```
url <- "https://pikobar.jabarprov.go.id/distribution-case#"
df <- url %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>% 
  html_table(fill = T)
```

I saw someone using `lapply` to make it into a tidy table, but when I tried it looked like a mess because I'm new to this.
Can anybody help me? I really frustated

Comment: What data exactly are you hoping to retrieve from that page? What should your desired output look like? What happened with you lapply code? And what isn't working with your code above?

Comment: Covid data by region, the one that shown as table. Data frame. I never use lapply, in fact, I can never detect the data. The code that I used never detect the data, in some trial, I just get first row of the data and didn't know how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't scrape the data in the table by `rvest` because it's requested to this link:
https://dashboard-pikobar-api.digitalservice.id/v2/sebaran/pertumbuhan?wilayah=kota&=32 with the `api-key` attached.

```
pg <- httr::GET(
  "https://dashboard-pikobar-api.digitalservice.id/v2/sebaran/pertumbuhan?wilayah=kota&=32",
  config = httr::add_headers(`api-key` = "480d0aeb78bd0064d45ef6b2254be9b3")
)
data <- httr::content(pg)$data
```

I don't know if the `api-key` works in the future but it works for now as I see.

Comment: How can you know that since I didn't give that information to you? Knowing this info will help me solve similar problem in the future.

Comment: Actually the gov site provide API to public, but that's data didn't updated so I decided to scrap directly from the website. The link that you show, bring me to slightly different link to the API that gov give.

Comment: @NursahidAssafaat The idea is that if the page doesn't contain the data itself, it has to send requests somewhere to get the data. You can look at the Network tab in the Dev tool to see all the requests that have been sent.

Comment: Wow I get it now. Thanks you very much, I the data source and the api key